# FactoryGirl Sequence not instantiating when creating an object with association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have to write a few tests for a controller I have. I have 3 models : User, UserInfo and UserPaymentPreference. I am using FactoryGirl to make a UserPaymentPreference object like this:

```
factory :advertiser_payment_preference_sequence do
      association :advertiser_user, factory: [:advertiser_user_sequence]
    end

factory :advertiser_user_sequence, class: 'AdvertiserUser' do
      deposit { rand(100..1000).round(2) }
      sequence(:login) { |n| "#{Faker::Internet.domain_name}#{n}" }
      user_type 'advertiser'
      association :user_info, factory: :advertiser_user_info_sequence

      trait :no_deposit do
        deposit 0
      end
    end

factory :advertiser_user_info_sequence, class: 'AdvertiserUserInfo' do
      sequence(:firstname) { |n| "#{Faker::Name.first_name}#{n}" }
      sequence(:organization) { |n| "#{Faker::Company.name}#{n}" }
      sequence(:phone) { |n| "#{Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone}#{n}" }
      sequence(:fiscal_code) { |n| "#{Faker::Company.duns_number}#{n}" }
      sequence(:address) { |n| "#{Faker::Address.street_address}#{n}" }
      sequence(:city) { |n| "#{Faker::Address.city}#{n}" }
    end
```

This works fine if I do something like FactoryGirl.build(:advertiser_user_info_sequence) it will create an object of type UserInfo with all the fields populated as they should be.

However when I try to make an AdvertiserPaymentPreference object by doing FactoryGirl.build(:advertiser_payment_preference_sequence) all the user_info fields will be "" instead of the value that it should have been created by the association.

```
describe 'Advertiser::Billing::SettingsController', type: :request do
  let!(:campaign) { create :campaign }
  let!(:user) { campaign.user }
  let!(:user_info) { user.user_info }
  let!(:advertiser_payment_preference) { create(:advertiser_payment_preference, advertiser_user_id: user.id)}

  before :each do
    login(user)
  end

  describe "PUT/PATCH /advertiser/billing/settings" do
    context "it is a valid request" do
      it "updates the resource" do
        binding.pry
        new_advertiser_payment_preference = build(:advertiser_payment_preference_sequence)

        binding.pry
        params = {}
        params['user_info'] = to_api_advertiser_info(new_advertiser_user_info)
        api_put '/advertiser/billing/profile', params

        expect(response.status).to eq(200)

        user_info.reload
        expect(user_info.organization).to eq(new_advertiser_user_info.organization)
        expect(user_info.phone).to eq(new_advertiser_user_info.phone)
        expect(user_info.fiscal_code).to eq(new_advertiser_user_info.fiscal_code)
        expect(user_info.country).to eq(new_advertiser_user_info.country)
        expect(user_info.address).to eq(new_advertiser_user_info.address)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is how the test for the controller looks like . When I call new_advertiser_payment_preference = build(:advertiser_payment_preference_sequence) I get an object user_info with "" on all fields that are made using advertser_user_info_sequence.